# Why is my dynamic paint image sequence coming out blank?

Tags: animation, vertices, image, baking, dynamic-paint

I am trying out a project with blood smudging on the floor, and doing it with vertex mode is cooking my potato laptop, when I tried to bake it into an image sequence, its coming out blank.

[image]

I have checked all the Necessary options, I think. Please help.

[image]

Link to .blend:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1frJXE78Z5R8thPltGo9Bai67M3MHuPxJ/view?usp=sharing

Link to inspiration Video:https://youtu.be/pDr_Jqjd7zQ
Time Stamp: 0:05-0:08

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your subdivisions of your plane is far too big. So just make your plane much (!) smaller or subdivide it more (which i do not recommend if you do not want to crash your computer) - i just made your plane really tiny (after i rebought a new computer when i tried to subdivide it more...) and then  bake your images again and i got small red lines on the pngs. But i think your Shader setup is wrong too because i never saw red lines on the plane.

Comment: Thanks, I shall do that and get back to you.